# Value assignment is faling

Tags: object, google-apps-script

I'm working with some object-oriented google app scripts.  I'm creating my first test object and some of the passed arguments are being assigned to the internal variables, and some are not.  All of the arguments are strings.  Here's a clip of my constructor method and the logging output.

```
      constructor(desc, start, end){
        this.desc = desc;
    Logger.log('object start: %s, %s', start, this.start);    
        this.start = start;
    Logger.log('object start: %s, %s', start, this.start);    
        this.end = end;
```

I feel like there's something staring me in the face that I'm missing, but how can the assignment of the argument to the internal variable simply not happen?
Logger output:

```
2:20:55 PM  Info    object start: 20220017, null
2:20:55 PM  Info    object start: 20220017, null
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete script for your object.  Your Logger.log commands are before the property is defined.

Comment: I originally only had the 2nd logger command, but wanted to see if anything was different before the logger command.  Below is the section of code that creates the instance of the object.  The full project is multiple scripts and pages of code.  I am migrating from a method-based project to object-oriented since that is what I was used to in college.

Comment: code snippet
```
  var events = (searchText == '') ? calendar.getEvents(startDate, endDate) : calendar.getEvents(startDate, endDate, {search: searchText});
Logger.log(events[0].getStartTime());
var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(events[0].getStartTime(), 'America/Chicago', 'yyyymmdd');
var endDate = Utilities.formatDate(events[0].getEndTime(), 'America/Chicago', 'yyyymmdd');
var test = new rsvn(events[0].getDescription(), startDate, endDate);
Logger.log('start: %s, end: %s', startDate, endDate);
```

Comment: logger output

```
3:59:57 PM Info start: 20220017, end: 20220020
3:59:57 PM Info object start: 20220017, null
3:59:57 PM Info object start: 20220017, null
```

Comment: I can not explain your situation.  I use object oriented programming in Google App Script all the time and have never encountered this.  Have you checked the value after the instance of the object is created, `rsvn.start`?

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

Here is a simple test of an object constructor in Google App Script

**Script**

```
function dummy() {
  try {
    var obj = new TestObject(1,2,3);
    console.log("obj.var1 = "+obj.getVar1);
    console.log("obj.var3 = "+obj.getVar3);
    obj.setVar3 = 10;
    console.log("obj.var3 = "+obj.getVar3);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

class TestObject {
  constructor(var1,var2,var3) {
    console.log("this.var1 = "+this.var1)
    this.var1 = var1;
    console.log("this.var1 = "+this.var1)
    this.var2 = var2;
    this.var3 = var3;
  }
  get getVar1() { return this.var1; }
  get getVar2() { return this.var2; }
  get getVar3() { return this.var3; }
  set setVar1(var1) { this.var1 = var1; }
  set setVar2(var2) { this.var2 = var2; }
  set setVar3(var3) { this.var3 = var3; }
}
```

**Console.log**

```
7:28:34 PM  Notice  Execution started
7:28:36 PM  Info    this.var1 = undefined
7:28:36 PM  Info    this.var1 = 1
7:28:36 PM  Info    obj.var1 = 1
7:28:36 PM  Info    obj.var3 = 3
7:28:36 PM  Info    obj.var3 = 10
7:28:34 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor

Comment: I copied the three scripts from the current project to a new project, in case there was some sort of interference from the other script files.  Once I did this (using copy/paste), the value assignment worked properly.  Even with renaming the internal variable and argument names, the issue occurred in the original project, but did not in the new project.  I'll continue to investigate to find how code that was not called was possibly conflicting.  If I solve it, I'll post again.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the ultimate cause of the problem.

There is a limitation when created classes: the arguments passed to the constructor cannot have an associated setter method.  As soon as I commented the setter method out, the initialization of the internal variable worked as expected.  This is not a limitation that I came across when reading up on javascript-specific object-oriented programming.